# Full Calendar sync with Zimbra Calendar

Tags: synchronization, fullcalendar, zimbra

I am new to Calendar sync. I have been searching around on how to sync Full Calendar with Zimbra Calendar but I couldn't find any resources online but the most popular calendar sync with Google, iOS, Thunderbird, Outlook and etc. Furthermore, Zimbra Calendar only provides GET and IMPORT appointments REST API which is not a sync. My app has CRUD operations for appointments and shows all in FullCalendar. I have looked thru some documentation of CalDav, curl and etc. I am little confused on which is the best for the sync. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us a link to the docs for the Zimbra REST API please

Comment: https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_REST_API_Reference here you go

Comment: It looks like you can use https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_REST_API_Reference:Import_Appointments to add one or more new events to the Zimbra calendar. Annoying you have to format it as ics first instead of JSON, but there you go. Not sure how you would go about updating or deleting though. Sorry but it looks to me like what you want to do (CRUD operations) is simply not supported by this API. Perhaps if you are able to contact Zimbra support they could let you know if there's any alternative. (I found this question via the fullCalendar tag, I know nothing about Zimbra unfortunately.)

Comment: Okay. That's what I am concerned with too. Thanks a lot.